# Refactoring Rubocop Style/GuardClause in a more readable/maintainable way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

**Rubocop complains:** Style/GuardClause: Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression.
    if issue_flag == true && issue_notification_sent && !issue_notification_follow_up_sent && send_follow_up
    ^^

My original code is

```
if issue_flag == true && issue_notification_sent && !issue_notification_follow_up_sent && send_follow_up
  email_address = "sales@test.com"
  puts "Emailing Follow Up #{email_address} - #{sales_order}"
  UserMailer.issue_notification(self, email_address).deliver_now
  update(issue_notification_follow_up_sent: true)
end
```

and from reading the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause), it seems that I can solve this by implementing the following code instead:

```
return unless issue_flag == true && issue_notification_sent && !issue_notification_follow_up_sent && send_follow_up
email_address = "sales@test.com"
puts "Emailing Follow Up #{email_address} - #{sales_order}"
UserMailer.issue_notification(self, email_address).deliver_now
update(issue_notification_follow_up_sent: true)
```

I can see that this essentially breaks early from the method unless the condition is met, but to me, this seems less readable.  It also seems less maintainable as further conditionals cannot be added after this code unless they pass the condition on the first line, for instance, to execute something else if `issue_flag == true && !issue_notification_sent` (anything matching this condition would have already returned on line 1 of the refactored code above).

Is there a better way to refactor this so that more conditions could be added after the code below, without the code returning prematurely?

Thanks.

Comment: Having four conditions in a row concatenated with `&&` is already a code smell. When you will need to add more conditions you’d better refactor the whole codepiece to avoid `if`s at all. Early return is a way to go here.

Comment: Guard clauses are a specific pattern that prevents the method from being run (or provides early exit) unless preconditions are satisfied. You can have multiple guards, which can simplify the expression somewhat. If you need an `else` clause, or if you are executing different things based on different conditions, that is not a situation where guard clauses would be used (and I don't think you'd be getting a warning from Rubocop if that was the situation). Unfortunately, Rubocop can't read your mind or tell the future, it can only comment on your code as it is in that moment.

Comment: neither of these is really readable, mainly because the first line is too long. Simple fix would be to extract that to a method, and split it up on multiple lines (80 chars is a good limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can do something like below

```
# issue_flag is boolean so we can directly put it
# create a new method with all the condition and give a proper name
return unless issue_flag && send_follow_up? # change name accourdingly
  email_address = "sales@test.com"
  puts "Emailing Follow Up #{email_address} - #{sales_order}"
  UserMailer.issue_notification(self, email_address).deliver_now
  update(issue_notification_follow_up_sent: true)
end
# document its behaviour
def send_follow_up?
  issue_notification_sent && !issue_notification_follow_up_sent && send_follow_up
end
```

The guard structure is used to send the control out of block so if you need change something or do something after the condition then you will not be able to use the guard clause. Have a look at the below code in such scenarios we will not use guard clause

```
def test
  if something_here?
    do_something
  end

  do_something_else
  do_something_else1
  do_something_else2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably extract most part of the method as privates with clear names that tells the intention. Pseudocode implementation would look like this:

```
def method_name
  return unless flag? && issue_notification_sent_with_follow_up

  log_follow_up
  UserMailer.issue_notification(self, @email_address).deliver_now
  update(issue_notification_follow_up_sent: true)
end

private

def flag?
  issue_flag == true
end

def issue_notification_sent_with_follow_up
  issue_notification_sent && !issue_notification_follow_up_sent && send_follow_up
end

def log_follow_up
  @email_address = "sales@test.com"
  puts "Emailing Follow Up #{@email_address} - #{sales_order}"
end
```